# global tables in a single header?

Tags: c

I want to have a single header to include some code. The code below works fine if you compile it as `g++ a.c b.c`, however I'd want this to work on C files/compilers. I'm getting the error `multiple definition of 'mytable'` What can I do? I prefer to have the table visible so the compiler can inline it. If you use `-O2` and look at the c++ build you can see both function is a simple return because it knew the table data. How do I do this in C?

```
a.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#else
#define constexpr
#endif
constexpr inline int mytable[]={5, 8};
inline int myfunc(int v) { return mytable[v&1]; }
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

//a.c
#include "a.h"
int a() { return myfunc(1); }
int b();
int main() {
    return a() + b();
}

//b.c
#include "a.h"
int b() { return myfunc(0); }
```

Comment: Have you tried `static`?

Comment: Can you put `mytable` inside the `myfunc` function definition?

Comment: I don'tthink C allows `inline` to be applied to variables, so I'm not sure how this compiles as C, unless you used a macro to define `inline` as empty?

Comment: @TomKarzes it seemed to ignore it but I now notice in debug builds the linker complains about no definition for myfunc :( I always heard c is more straightforward than C++. I guess it's not always true. `static` did seem to work for the table but got me a warning

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas That gets me a warning but the function in each file seems to inline the data. So maybe this is what I'll use

Answer (score 2):

Some people prefer to put the definition of `mytable` in a `.c` file:

```
// usual.c -- initialize a global

int mytable[] = { 5, 8 };
```

But, whenever I see (e.g.) `mytable` in a `.h` file:

```
// usual.h -- declare a global

extern int mytable[];
```

I'm left with searching for the definition amongst all the `.c` files to find it in `usual.c`

---

I prefer to put both the declaration and definition of `mytable` in the same `.h` file. Then, IMO, it's easier to see what's going on without having to search through a bunch of files:

```
// mytable.h -- declare/define mytable array

#ifdef GLOBAL_MYTABLE
int mytable[] = { 5, 8 };
#else
extern int mytable[];
#endif
```

And, then force the definition with:

```
// define.c -- define as global

#define GLOBAL_MYTABLE
#include "mytable.h"
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Work != Compile. So this compiles and executes fine but my goal is to have the functions in both files (a and b) to be able to inline the data into the function, which doesn't happen using this solution. Right now static appears to work but I get a warning about it being used in an inline function. Also debug modes aren't happy I have no concrete functions so I'll need to figure that out to. C++ was easy –
> Stan

I'm not completely sure what you mean, but I'll make a guess based upon what some of the "usual" problems are.

In `mytable.h`, we can put `inline` functions in directly. We can add function *prototypes*:

```
// mytable.h -- declare/define mytable array

#ifdef GLOBAL_MYTABLE
int mytable[] = { 5, 8 };
#else
extern int mytable[];
#endif

// NOTE: for C, we [usually] want "static inline"
static inline int
myfunc(int v)
{
    return mytable[v & 1];
}

// function prototypes:
int a(void);
int b(void);
```

Now, we put the actual functions into a `.c` file:

```
// ab.c -- define a and b functions

#include "mytable.h"

int
a(void)
{
    return myfunc(1);
}

int
b(void)
{
    return myfunc(0);
}
```

Note that [in the previous example], we put the `#define GLOBAL_MYTABLE` in `define.c`. This was arbitrary. With the new `ab.c`, we could put it there instead (as long as only one `.c` has `#define GLOBAL_MYTABLE` we're fine).

An additional trick that I use is to use a `#define` for `inline` function attributes. I often want to *force* the functions to be inlined, no matter what:

```
// inline.h -- define inline functions

#define inline_always   static inline __attribute__((always inline))
#define inline_never    __attribute__((noinline))

// NOTE: for C, we [usually] want "static inline"
inline_always int
myfunc(int v)
{
    return mytable[v & 1];
}

// function prototypes:
inline_never int a(void);
inline_never int b(void);
```

One of the advantages is that you define the "cumbersome" syntax in one place.

Another is that the `#define inline_*` can be bracketed with `#ifdef __cplusplus` blocks to define them differently for C or C++.

*Side note:* Nowadays, for C, `static inline` is the way to go, but this wasn't always the case. IIRC, it was once `extern inline`???. Because, I had such `#define`, when the requirement changed, I just changed the `#define` in one place instead of a myriad of places in many `.h` files.

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> To clarify, I mean look at the source of this, then uncomment the table and see how the functions now use literals. I'm trying to get a solution that uses literals for each file and it seems like static is working even though the compiler warns me about using it with inline godbolt.org/z/fn4W9bv8M –
> Stan

I'm [mostly] talking about C [because that's what you asked about]:

> How do I do this in C?

But, your link is compiling with C++

Again, I'm not sure what you mean by "literals" in this context unless you mean *initializers* such as: `int mytable[] = { 5, 8 };`

As I'm familiar with it, "literal" is more in the context of `char` arrays and `char *` pointers:

```
// NOTE: here "hello" is an initializer and _not_ a string literal
// string_array will end up in the .data section
// the string data will be linked into/at the address of string_array
char string_array[] = "hello";

// here "world" is [read only] string literal
// string_pointer will end up in the .data section
// the string _data_ will be at a different address in the .rodata section
char *string_pointer = "world";
```

If you put your godbolt code snippet in a *single* `.c` or `.cpp` file, you're fine. That is what godbolt is showing.
For reference, here is your godbolt code (with the comment removed):

```
extern const int mytable[];

int myfunc(int v) { return mytable[v&1]; }
int a() { return myfunc(1); }
int b() { return myfunc(0); }
int main() {
    return a() + b();
}
const int mytable[]={5, 8};
```

But, if you put it in a `.h` file (e.g. `mytable.h`) and then have *two* `.c` files (e.g. `foo.c` and `bar.c`) that do `#include "mytable.h"`, when you *link* them, you'll get "multiple definition" errors.

This is true when compiling for C or C++.

That is what my above examples are meant to avoid/remedy.

Again, if you're talking about a single `.c` file, you *can* do:

```
extern int mytable[];

int mytable[] = { 5, 8 };
```

This will work with or without the `extern`.

Generally, you do *not* want to *define* global/reusable functions in a `.h` file (e.g. `a` or `b` and [definitely not] `main`). Put them in a `.c` (e.g. `ab.c` from my example above). Put function *prototypes* in the `.h` (e.g. `mytable.h` in my example above).

If you have *inline* functions, you *do* want to put the full definitions in your `.h` file.

In C, they [used to] need `static`. However, I think C++ is different. That is, it will complain about the `static`.

And, in my trial compilation in C for this, `inline` by itself seemed okay. So, things have changed since I last had to deal with this [from a few years back]. I'm guessing this is "feature creep" from C++ to allow more cross compatibility.

I'm using `gcc` 8.3.1 but not all C compilers may be so advanced. In the past, `static inline` was required to resolve linker errors [in an earlier version]. It's conservative and works (with little harm). So, if you do the `#define inline_*` method I mentioned, you can quickly change things to suit a given compiler/linker environment.

You only want to put [global scope] non-static function prototypes in a `.h` file (e.g. `int a(void);`) as I did in `mytable.h` in my first update section.

Comment: Work != Compile. So this compiles and executes fine but my goal is to have the functions in both files (a and b) to be able to inline the data into the function, which doesn't happen using this solution. Right now static appears to work but I get a warning about it being used in an inline function. Also debug modes aren't happy I have no concrete functions so I'll need to figure that out to. C++ was easy

Comment: To clarify, I mean look at the source of this, then uncomment the table and see how the functions now use literals. I'm trying to get a solution that uses literals for each file and it seems like static is working even though the compiler warns me about using it with inline https://godbolt.org/z/fn4W9bv8M

Comment: @Stan I've updated my answer to try to address your godbolt example--YMMV

Comment: Great effort. My solution ended up being `static inline` which seems to have every compile unit be able to optimize the function with the data in the table. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75872213/20652462

Answer (score 2):

Just as a call for sanity... if you compile this code with gcc -O3 (x86):

```
int myfunc(int v ) 
{ 
  static const int mytable[]={5, 8};
  return mytable[v&1]; 
}
```

Then you get the machine code

```
and     edi, 1
mov     eax, DWORD PTR mytable.0[0+rdi*4]
```

And if compiling this obfuscated, non-standard code with the same compiler and compiler options:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#else
#define constexpr
#endif
constexpr inline int mytable[]={5, 8};
inline int myfunc(int v) { return mytable[v&1]; }
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
  printf("%d\n", myfunc(1));
}
```

Then we essentially get the very same machine code (the bitwise AND got optimized out since I included `main()`):

```
    mov     esi, DWORD PTR mytable[rip+4]
```

Thus the solution to all your problems is to ditch whatever you are attempting and instead use the plain, readable code from my first example instead. Can it get inlined well? Yes/no/maybe - who cares. Do you have an actual extreme performance bottleneck that prevents you from using a few CPU ticks of function call overhead?